# SQL finding mismatches within the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL Noob here.
I'm struggling with a (hopefully) simple SQL query and would appreciate if someone could help me understand if what I'm trying to do is even possible. I already completed the task outside SQL so this is just my curiosity.

Task is simple.
I have a Table with millions of Codes. There are 12 digit codes always starting with '00000' and their 7 digit equivalents. (like 000001234567 and 1234567)
I'd need to identify all 12 digit codes that DO NOT have equivalent 7 digit code within the same column. Keep in mind there can be other 7 digit codes without a 12 digit equivalent (like 6789012)

Any help appreciated.

This is the data of the table :

| Code |
| --- |
| 000001234567 |
| 1234567 |
| 000002345678 |
| 2345678 |
| 000003456789 |
| 000004567891 |
| 000005678912 |
| 6789012 |
| ... |

and the expected output is :

| Code |
| --- |
| 000003456789 |
| 000004567891 |
| 000005678912 |
| ... |

Comment: What's your DBMS, and expected result considering the currently presented sample data ( Presumably `000003456789`, `000004567891` , `000005678912` ) ?

Comment: mysql and expected result as you presumed is correct (12 digit codes without 7digit equivalents)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`TRIM()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function and `HAVING` clause along with `GROUP BY` such as

```sql
 SELECT CONCAT('00000',TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM code))
   FROM t
  GROUP BY CONCAT('00000',TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM code)) 
  HAVING COUNT(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM code))=1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3aa0164be1be9f20e2f76ad5519036eb)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you and I apologize, I probably should have specified, that there can be other 7char codes without 12char equivalents. For example adding 6789012 to the initial table then shows 000006789012 in the results, which is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this assuming that the longer string has 12chars with '00000' in the beginning

```
 select ID from TABLE t1
      where 
      select count (*) from TABLE t2 where substring(t1.ID, 6, 12) <> t2.ID) = 0
```

Comment: I would use 'where not exists(SELECT * FROM ....) this is more clear

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways of doing this. You can use functions such as Trim to remove the leading 0's or RIGHT to take the last 7 digits and compare. As an example you could do

```
SELECT CODE
FROM TABLE
WHERE LENGTH(CODE) = 12
AND TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM CODE) NOT IN 
   (SELECT CODE
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE LENGTH(CODE) = 7
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(code , UNSIGNED) as c,
   COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY CONVERT(code , UNSIGNED)
HAVING COUNT(*)<>2
;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee06bcdb57c6bd34e5941caa62201fec)

The maximum value of an unsigned number is [4294967295](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), so converting to UNSIGNED is long enough to hold your numbers, because they have maximal 7 digits.

Comment: You presumably wanted to write `HAVING COUNT(*)=1`, didn't you ?

Comment: Why? I only want to see the records that do not exist 2 times, that's why I am using `<>2`  (But the result is the same, in this case)

Comment: The requirement that those left padded zeros should be in the result set is added AFTER I posted this _answer_.  I cannot help that changing a question is allowed any time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a SELF JOIN and do some string manipulation for the join then just filter the codes which produces NULL for their equivalent codes.

```
WITH codes AS
( 
  SELECT '000001234567' AS code UNION ALL 
  SELECT '1234567' AS code UNION ALL 
  SELECT '000002345678' AS code UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2345678' AS code UNION ALL 
  SELECT '000003456789' AS code UNION ALL 
  SELECT '000004567891' AS code UNION ALL 
  SELECT '000005678912' AS code  
)
 SELECT 
   c.code,
   cc.code AS equivalent_code
 FROM 
   codes c
   LEFT JOIN codes cc ON RIGHT(c.code, 7) = cc.code
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(c.code) > 7
 AND cc.code IS NULL
```